# Developing AWS infrastructure provisioning ansible playbook using check / dry-run

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I am trying to provision AWS infrastructure using ansible. My simplified playbook `vpc.yml` for illustration is as follow:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    vpc_name:           "Test VPC"
    vpc_cidr_block:     "10.0.0.0/16"
    aws_region:         "ap-east-1"
    subnets:
      test_net_1a:
        az:             "ap-east-1a"
        cidr:           "10.0.1.0/24"
      test_net_1a:
        az:             "ap-east-1b"
        cidr:           "10.0.2.0/24"

  tasks:

    - name:               Create VPC
      ec2_vpc_net:
        name:             "{{ vpc_name }}"
        cidr_block:       "{{ vpc_cidr_block }}"
        region:           "{{ aws_region }}"
        state:            "present"
      register: my_vpc

    # Save VPC id in a new variable.
    - name:               Set VPC ID in variable
      set_fact:
        vpc_id:           "{{ my_vpc.vpc.id }}"

    - name:               Create Subnets
      ec2_vpc_subnet:
        state:            "present"
        vpc_id:           "{{ vpc_id }}"
        cidr:             "{{ item.value.cidr }}"
        az:               "{{ item.value.az }}"
        region:           "{{ aws_region }}"
        resource_tags:
          Name:           "{{ item.key }}"
      loop: "{{ subnets | dict2items }}"
```

Now I try to test my playbook with `ansible-playbook vpc.yml --check`. However the playbook would fail because with `--check` my_vpc would return:

```
"changed": true,
"failed": false
```

Apparently `--check` cannot be used to preview AWS provisioning changes using ansible, so how do I test my playbook during development without making any actual infrastructure changes?

Comment: I'm interested to read what other people say. In my experience, I always need to run the playbooks against something similar to the real thing. What I usually do is test roles that provision infrastructure with the actual cloud provider (on a test account).  For roles that provision/configure software I use Vagrant to fine tune the role and then move to test with the actual cloud provider.

Comment: I don't think so it is supported with --check option for cloud providers. Supporting such functionality will be quite helpful. For now may be you can use the aws cli with `--dry-run` option using command module delegated to localhost or to an aws instance with an IAM role attached to it. -- but you can't use the built in modules of ansible for aws

Comment: It sounds like using ansible to provision infrastructure is a bad choice, as Cloudformation supports changesets and Terraform supports plan. I don't feel safe making production changes without a way to preview its effect beforehand.

Comment: I would not say a bad choice would rather say better option are available :). If the cloud is only aws then I would suggest to use cloudformation along with ansible jinja2 template. Create a cfn jinja2 template pass vars create a cfn then deploy cfn